# Is there any way to use GeoJSON conveniently with Geomesa?

Tags: gis, geomesa

I wouldn't like to build a `Geomesa Datastore`, just want to use the `Geomesa Spark Core/SQL` module to do some spatial analysis process on spark. My data sources are some GeoJson files on hdfs. However, I have to create a `SpatialRDD` by `SpatialRDDProvider`.

There is a `Converter RDD Provider` example in the documents of Geomesa:

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.geotools.data.Query
import org.locationtech.geomesa.spark.GeoMesaSpark

val exampleConf = ConfigFactory.load("example.conf").root().render()
val params = Map(
  "geomesa.converter"        -> exampleConf,
  "geomesa.converter.inputs" -> "example.csv",
  "geomesa.sft"              -> "phrase:String,dtg:Date,geom:Point:srid=4326",
  "geomesa.sft.name"         -> "example")
val query = new Query("example")
val rdd = GeoMesaSpark(params).rdd(new Configuration(), sc, params, query)
```

I can choose GeoMesa's `JSON Converter` to create the SpatialRDD. However, it seems to be 
necessary to assign all field names and types in `geomesa.sft` paramater and a converter config file. If I have many GeoJson files, I have to do this one by one manually, it is very 
inconvenient obviously.

Is there any way that Geomesa Converter can infer the field names and types from the file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, GeoMesa can infer the type and converter. For scala/java, see this [unit test](https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/geomesa_2.11-2.4.0/geomesa-convert/geomesa-convert-json/src/test/scala/org/locationtech/geomesa/convert/json/JsonConverterTest.scala#L1227). Alternatively, the GeoMesa CLI tools can be used ahead of time to persist the type and converter to reusable files, using the [convert](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/cli/export.html#convert) command (type inference is described in the linked [ingest](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/cli/ingest.html#cli-ingest) command).